Stack Overflow UI renders weird on Edge on iPad
It loads fine for a second,

and then after a second, it renders like below:

I have tried switching themes, clearing browser data and it doesn’t help. I tried reinstalling the browser app as a last resort and didn’t work either. SO renders fine on other browsers or on other devices, so it doesn’t seem to be associated with my account either.
I appreciate all suggestions that could help fix this.
EDIT:
OS: iPadOS 17.4.1
BROWSER: MS Edge 123.0.2420.90

You might have enabled some settings for visually impaired users

Are you using some extensions / browser specific settings? The first image looks like dark mode with high contrast enabled but the colors look different from what they actually should be.

Can you reproduce this in an incognito tab? Or in a different browser? (Not sure why you'd even install edge on an iPad)

@derpirscher is this an SO setting? It doesn’t seem to affect other websites. How can I turn that off?

@AbdulAzizBarkat browser is set to use the system theme, which is dark mode. That’s about it. No extensions,

@Cerbrus yes the effect persists on incognito tabs. It renders fine on safari. I use edge because everything syncs across all devices, and is more memory efficient version of chrome.

Please provide your Operating system and OS version, and your browser version.

@Makyen done, i found a fix which I shared as an answer, but idk why SO's native theme would be messed up the browser's forced dark mode. it seems to be the same implementation across all chromium distros

Edge on iPad has a setting under appearance (Settings → Appearance) to enable dark themes for all websites that was interfering with SO’s native dark theme. I turned it off. Everything has gone back to normal. Weirdly, it doesn’t affect other websites that have native dark themes.
It makes sense why the website would load fine for a second and then the browser would do its thing after.
Edit: Added image showing SO light mode under Edge forced Dark mode. Has the same issue. 

It's even weirder that it's not a problem on any of the other domains in the company, like Stack Exchange, which is why I classed this as a bug on the question I posted. My question was marked as a duplicate. However, even though @sam-thomas, your answer 'answers' the question, and finds a user-land solution, it does not highlight this unexpected behaviour to the SO devs, and so the 'bug' is unresolved and will continue to trip future users up.

@orionrush I'd guess it's because only [SO], its localized sites ([pt.so], [es.so], [ru.so], [ja.so]), and [sound.se] have a proper native dark theme.

How does Edge's dark mode look on SO when SO is set to "Light" mode?

@orionrush is right, it doesn't affect any other stack sites. just SO. For example, this meta website does not have a dark theme. but converts to dark beautifully when edge tries to.

@AndrewT. I think its the other way around.. native dark themes conflict. see above comment.

@Makyen edited answer to include image
